# App appears on "Versions" but not on dashboard

Tags: android, ios, version, crashlytics, google-fabric

I'm having problem with one app, it's working fine on iOS, but on Android it does not appear on the dashboard. If I check inside Organization -> App Name -> Versions I can see it, but it never shows on the dashboard.

Another programmer here is having the same issue with a different app, but on iOS.

I checked FabricSettings but everything seems to be correct.

Answer (score 0):

The application will appear on DashBoard automatically after you set up Fabric on your application correctly and launching for the first time.

Comment: What do you mean by set up correctly? It's working for iOS. 
And I already launched on Android several times between yesterday and today. As I said on the post, it appears only on the versions tab inside settings (right after launch on the device) but never on the dashboard.

Comment: Have you tried to create a crash in the Android application to see whether you can get an email notification?

Comment: Forcing a crash does make the version appear on the dashboard (but not the crash though O.o)